# How to match the key and value of the map return type?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on a method where the return type for the *getOrdersForCustomer* method is `Map<Integer, List<Order>>` and each customerId (Integer of the map) needs to go with their respective orders while iterating through a List of orders. Order is already associated with customer Id. I ended up with the following:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Order>> getOrdersForCustomer(Company company) {

    List<Order> orders = orderDao.findAll(company);
    Map<Integer, List<Order>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Order order: orders){

        int customerId = order.getCustomerId();
        if( map.get(customerId).size() ==0){

            map.put( customerId, new ArrayList<Order>());
        }

        else{

            map.get(customerId).add(order);
        }
    }

    return map; 
}
```

How to correct the code to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting an NPE here?

```
if( map.get(customerId).size() ==0){
```

Do:

```
if (!map.contains(customerId)) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if the first Order object will not be added to the List in the Map. I believe that you should always do the add in every iteration of the for:

for(Order order: orders)
{
        int customerId = order.getCustomerId();

```
    if( map.get(customerId).size() ==0){

        map.put( customerId, new ArrayList<Order>());
    }

    map.get(customerId).add(order);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this check. If the customerId is not in the map, you'll get a null pointer exception.

```
 if( map.get(customerId).size() ==0) {
   map.put( customerId, new ArrayList<Order>());
  }
```

The logic is also not correct. You haven't added the order into the list that you're adding. You can either add the order into the list constructor or remove the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was a mistake in the logic and I corrected it suggested by @djechlin as following,

```
@Override
public Map<Integer, List<Order>> getOrdersForCustomer(Company company) {

    List<Order> orders = orderDao.findAll(company);
    Map<Integer, List<Order>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(Order order: orders){

        int customerId = order.getCustomerId();
        if(!map.containsKey(customerId)){

            map.put(customerId, new ArrayList<Order>());
        }

        map.get(customerId).add(order);
    }

    return map; 
}
```